# Editable title bar in sharepoint wikipage

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

i have wikipage defined in site pages. And when i click Edit Page -> Title Bar Properties nothing happens. I try this two things:

[link one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/38702097-cfca-4b83-9ec1-19fab0c6d830/sharepoint-title-bar-on-internet-explorer-cant-change?forum=sharepointadminlegacy),
[link two](http://anothersharepointblog.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/title-bar-properties-button-is-disabled-in-sharepoint-2010/)

In my sitepage there is this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="my title" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/> - 
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

My title is now "my title". But i want to allow edit this title to admins of web through Title Bar Properties button and not through the sharepoint designer.
Any ideas how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert an `SharePoint:ListItemProperty` linking to the title property instead of an EncodedLiteral (which is static in this case).

So in your case you should change your Wiki page template to this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

I wrote an [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17557.sharepoint-2013-change-page-title-in-wiki-sites.aspx) about that some time ago in the TechNet wiki.